# VISUAL BASIC search array for string

Tags: visual-studio, basic

I have an array of strings and a string. How can I search the array for all instances of the string occurring at all in the string?

So for example if the string I was looking for was "ea"

Beach, creak, eat, and sea would all come up as they have "ea" at least somewhere in the string.

How would I make the 'if' comparison for this?

```
target = inputbox("enter a string")
For index = 0 to 10
If name(index) Like "*target*"
Listbox.items.add(name)
```

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet of what you have tried so far so that we can help you better? See how to create a [Minimal,Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Vakore added code

Comment: @Vakore: Not necessary to write that you can't help. Just don't help.

Comment: @Haris: Visual Basic is not a language, per se, it is an IDE. Are you trying to write in .NET or VB6 or VBA? You need to specify these details or no one will/can help you.

Comment: Apologies, i am writing in .NET